# How to return the last item in ng-repeat to the controller

Tags: angularjs

I would like to run a string function, to remove the comma on the last span element.

```
<p class="genres">
    <span class="plabel">Genres</span>: 
    <span class="genre_name" ng-repeat="genres in movie.genres"
          ng-class="{'last': $last}">{{genres.name}}, 
    </span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `$last` boolean on a ternary operator inside interpolation:

`{{genres.name}} {{$last ? '' : ','}}`

> $last (boolean): true if the repeated element is last in the iterator.

If you want to perform more string manipulation, maybe you could also use an [Angular filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter): (Untested)

```
angular.module('testFilter', [])
.filter('addComma', function() {
  return function(input, shouldAddComma) {
    if (shouldAddComma)
       return input + ",";
    else 
       return input;
  };
});
```

And then in your HTML:

```
{{genres.name | addComma: $last}}
```

This is just an example of how you can use an Angular filter to modify the string and also receive a parameter.

Comment: Thanks. That will work for this, but there are other areas of my app that will require more string manipulation. How can I get the text of the span and pass it to a function of the controller?

Comment: Oh, you can totally do that. But maybe you want to check out [Angular Filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter).
You can declare a function on your controller's `$scope` and then call it passing the `genre.name` as a parameter, if you want to do it on your controller.

Comment: @ThomasGrauer would you flag this as Accepted Answer if it helped you? thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Just add [**`ng-if`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) like this

```
<span class="genre_name" ng-repeat="genres in movie.genres"
          ng-class="{'last': $last}">{{genres.name}}<label ng-if="!$last">,</label>
    </span>
```

Comment: why in a label? wouldn't a span be better suited..?

Comment: span inside span... I have added label in order to differentiate things. No specific reason though @baao